# Connect remote mysql to django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mysql-python, django-mysql

i have a MySQL database in cpanel and i want to connect my django project to this database when i try to connect it it show a message that i can't connect to localhost but i don't want to connect to localhost i want to connect to my remote database in cpanel.
i have tried to connect to (MySQL workbench) and it connected without a problem.

[This is a picture of my settings and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7FU1.jpg)

Comment: You have to enable remote access of your mysql db
Here you go for same problem: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/remote-access-to-mysql-not-working.632447/

Comment: please check this URL . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623468/connecting-django-to-remote-mysql-database-using-workbench